# One to one relationship or one to many relationship between repository and solution

Tags: asp.net, svn, tortoisesvn

I am developing a system that has four **DLLs** i.e.

```
1. business logic layer and three applications i.e. 
2. ASP.NET client
3. VB.NET client and 
4. mobile client.
```

I have created four separate **repositories** in **Tortoise SVN** for these.  I want to make a change that will affect all three client applications and may take several days to complete.  Would it be better to create one **repository** for all four projects putting them all in the trunk?

The question is: should I repository be created on a system basis (a system could contain multiple projects/DLLs) or on a project basis?

I have purchased a book on Tortoise/Subversion, which should arrive in a few days.  I suspect this will answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create separate repository for those which will be used in other project also. Include all other projects in same repository. Add the external repository using **svn:external**.